# requirement.txt installation is failing while building "orjson" on 64 bit python interpreter on 64 bit Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, rust, fastapi, rustup

Running requirements.txt installation for a project(Fast API). Ending up with below error. I have try approach from https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61925
and I have set up rust to "nightly" using `rustup override set nightly` still facing the error.

```
  Using cached orjson-3.4.3.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/c7/0n1qpwb16l55dfdwqs4xt97dhw2m6y/T/tmpwyr1rz66
         cwd: /private/var/folders/c7/0n1qpwb16l55dfdwqs4xt97dhw2m6y/T/pip-install-qmnttz7p/orjson
    Complete output (13 lines):
     maturin failed
      Caused by: Cargo metadata failed. Do you have cargo in your PATH?
      Caused by: Error during execution of `cargo metadata`: error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information
    
    Caused by:
      process didn't exit successfully: `rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names -Z mutable-noalias --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro --print=sysroot --print=cfg` (exit code: 1)
      --- stderr
      error: the option `Z` is only accepted on the nightly compiler
    
    
    Checking for Rust toolchain....
    Running `maturin pep517 write-dist-info --metadata-directory /private/var/folders/c7/0n1qpwb16l55dfdwqs4xt97dhw2m6y/T/pip-modern-metadata-c1upg8fc --interpreter /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2/bin/python3.8 --manylinux=off --strip=on`
    Error: Command '['maturin', 'pep517', 'write-dist-info', '--metadata-directory', '/private/var/folders/c7/0n1qpwb16l55dfdwqs4xt97dhw2m6y/T/pip-modern-metadata-c1upg8fc', '--interpreter', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2/bin/python3.8', '--manylinux=off', '--strip=on']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/c7/0n1qpwb16l55dfdwqs4xt97dhw2m6y/T/tmpwyr1rz66 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please advise!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the output of `rustup show`?

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed

`$ rustup show`
`Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin`
`rustup home:  /Users/user.name/.rustup`
`installed toolchains`
`--------------------`
`stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)`
`nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin`
`active toolchain`
`----------------`
`nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin (directory override for /Users/user.name/Documents/workspace/dts-api-poc')`
`rustc 1.50.0-nightly (1c389ffef 2020-11-24)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the error is with the maturin command using "Z" option which is only applicable in nightly compiler.  you can first try to install

Install nightly toolchain:

> rustup install nightly

Switch to nightly toolchain as default toolchain:

> rustup default nightly

and then try to install those dependencies.  Hope this works!!!!

Comment: ohhh, switching to `rustup default nightly` helped on my M1, thaaaanks

---

   Compiling marine-macro-impl v0.6.15
error[E0425]: cannot find function `get_fault_info` in this scope
   --> /Users/ivan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wasmer-runtime-core-fl-0.17.1/src/fault.rs:289:21
    |
289 |         let fault = get_fault_info(siginfo as _, ucontext);
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope